# Listing Elements with the same inodes in Groups

Tags: c

I have a program that scans the entire root directory and to get inodes, hardlinks counts and the file paths. the results is as follows:
  [image]

However i would like to group all the hardlinks linked to a particular inode together. At the end i would display the Inode , Hardlink count, and the grouped paths.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void scanDirectory(char *basePath){
    DIR* dir = opendir(basePath);
    struct dirent* dp;
    struct stat* statbuf = (struct stat*)malloc(sizeof(struct stat));

    if (!dir)
        return;

    while((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        if (dp->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path [1024];
            strcpy (path,basePath);
            strcat (path,dp->d_name);
            strcat (path,"/");
            scanDirectory(path);
        }
        else if(dp->d_type == DT_REG){
            char file [1024];
            strcpy (file,basePath);
            strcat (file,dp->d_name);

            if (stat(file, statbuf) == 0) {
                if(statbuf->st_nlink >1){
               printf("Inode:%ld    | Hardlink:  %d | %s \n",dp->d_ino, (unsigned int)statbuf->st_nlink, file); 
            }
            }
        }
    }
    free(statbuf);
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(){
    scanDirectory("/");  
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? How to create a list and sort it?

Comment: sorting, grouping the list according to the hard links

Comment: `stdlib` has sorting functions like [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) that might be helpful

Comment: it dint help with the desired results